# boost::multiindex and inheritance

Tags: linux, c++11, boost, boost-multi-index

I am trying to inherit from boot::multiindex and see what all I can do, while doing so insert works fine but replace is not.

Code

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct employee
{
  std::string name_;
  int id;
  int state;

  employee(std::string name, int id) 
      : name_{std::move(name)},
            id(id),
        state(0) {}


  employee(const employee& copy):
      name_(copy.name_),
      id(copy.id),
      state(copy.state){}
       
  bool operator<(const employee &a) const 
  { 
      return id < a.id; 
  }

  const std::string& get_name() const 
  { 
      return name_; 
  }

};

struct names{};

typedef multi_index_container<
  employee,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<
      identity<employee>
    >,
    hashed_unique<
      tag<names>,
        const_mem_fun<
        employee, const std::string&, &employee::get_name
      >
    >
  >
> employee_container;


typedef employee_container::index<names>::type::iterator employee_iterator_by_name;
//using employee_by_name = employee_container::nth_index<ANTENNA_INDEX_BY_NAME>::type&;

class employee_db: public employee_container
{
    public:
      void add_db(const employee& e)
      {
         this->insert(e);
      }  
      void update_db(
             employee_iterator_by_name& it
                )
      {
         this->replace(it, *it);
      }  


};
```

compiling it in Linux

```
gcc version 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5) (GCC) 

[sandbox@localhost multiindex]$ rpm -qa | grep boost | grep devel
boost-devel-1.66.0-7.el8.x86_64

[sandbox@localhost multiindex]$ g++  2.cc -c -std=c++11

2.cc: In member function ‘void employee_db::update_db(employee_iterator_by_name&)’:
2.cc:75:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘employee_db::replace(employee_iterator_by_name&, const value_type&)’
          this->replace(it, *it);
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `update_db` you're using an `employee_iterator_by_name`, which is an iterator to index #1, on the index #0 version (the default index) of `replace`. You want to use index #1 `replace`:

```
  void update_db(employee_iterator_by_name& it)
  {
     this->get<names>().replace(it, *it);
  }
```

I understand this is just some exploratory code, because calling `replace` this way does not change anything (you're replacing the value pointed to by `it` with, well, the value pointed to by `it`).

Comment: Yes its just illustration code. Actual one was lot bigger. Actually in real code I will fetch based on name and replace that .Thanks for pointing out the error.